# What is the grammar in "I was like"?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

In the sentence "I was like whatever", what is actually going on under the hood? "I" is presumably a pronoun, but what about the "was", the "like" and the "whatever"? Is the "was" on its own a verb? In which case what is the "like"? Or is "was like" as a whole a verb?

You might not like this, but that is a different matter. There is some discussion about that [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187402/replacement-for-the-annoying-habit-of-saying-i-was-like). Also, there is a discussion of its history [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313083/history-of-the-phrase-i-was-like-or-i-was-all). And I see from [The Boston Globe](https://www.bostonglobe.com/ideas/2015/01/25/linguists-are-like-get-used/ruUQoV0XUTLDjx72JojnBI/story.html) that this usage is called the "quotative like", but it still doesn't explain what is actually happening grammatically.

Comment: I'm not sure grammar could help here & now. I smiled when I read your question because often such expressions are in use for the simple reason we like them (I do 4 this one). Then, afterward, grammarians find us an answer ; I understand they haven't done yet !

Comment: Probably the sentence would be better written as, "I was like, 'Whatever.'"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a [grammarian](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grammarian), but here's my take on "I was like whatever"

[**I**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/I) - *pronoun*

> Used to refer to oneself as speaker or writer.

**was like** - comes from the idiomatic phrase "be like"

[**be like**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/like) - *informal*

> To say or utter. Used chiefly in oral narration: *"And he's **like**, "Leave me alone!"*

Some linguists do call this "quotative like", though it's not a well-defined thing so far. Here's a [long article](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~pgc/archive/2002/proc02/buchstaller02.pdf) by Prof. Dr. Isabelle Buchstaller, a variationist sociolinguist.

"And I’m Like, [Read This!](https://theamericanscholar.org/and-im-like-read-this/)" article by Jessica Love.

> The general consensus is that the quotative *like* encourages a speaker
>   to embody the participants in a conversation. Thus, the speaker
>   vocalizes the contents of participants’ utterances, but also her
>   *attitudes* toward those utterances. She can dramatize multiple
>   viewpoints, one after another, making it perfectly clear all the while
>   which views she sympathizes with and which she does not. Hear yourself
>   say these sentences aloud: *I walked up to Randy and he was like, Why
>   are you late? I was like, Because you gave me the wrong time!* You
>   have, in addition to relaying the he-says she-says bones of a
>   conversation, probably betrayed some moral indignation. Randy was
>   unreasonable, and you were in the right. It’s possible to do all this
>   with *says*, of course, but not nearly as naturally.
>
> The quotative *like* is often followed by filler words like *well* or
>   *dude*, as in *He was like, Dude, get your act together*. Much like a mask
>   or good make-up or the right dialect coaching, these fillers further
>   distinguish the current speaker from the person (or earlier self)
>   being quoted. They give the performance a bit of flair. (And make no
>   mistake: far from indicating laziness, the quotative *like* can inspire
>   some great performances.)

[**whatever**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whatever) - *interjection* *informal*

> Used to indicate indifference to or scorn for something, such as a remark or suggestion: We're having pizza tonight.— *"**Whatever**. I don't care."*

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I'm not a linguist, it's going to take a while to understand Prof. Dr. Isabelle Buchstaller's article.